# PyQt5 / PySide2 code only executes works with ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, pyqt5, pyside2

I have made a script extension for a programm called Nuke which opens a dialog with lineedit and allows the user to enter a label. However the script only executes setLabel() by pressing enter when there are only ascii characters in the lineedit.

[`text()`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLineEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.text) returns unicode and Nuke has no problem with special characters like äöü in labels if you do it through the normal ui

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import nuke
import sys
import os

class setLabelTool(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.n = node
        super(setLabelTool, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("Dialog")
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setFixedSize(199, 43)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 181, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.lineEdit.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        currentlabel = self.n['label'].value()
        if len(currentlabel) == 0:
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Set node label")
        else:
            self.lineEdit.setText(currentlabel)
            self.lineEdit.selectAll()

        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.setLabel)

    def setLabel(self):
        label = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.n['label'].setValue(label)
        print ("Node: " + self.n['name'].value() + " labeled " + label)
        self.close()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            print "Exit setLabelTool"
            self.close()

def showLabelTool():
    n = nuke.selectedNodes()[-1]
    if n != None:
        Tool = setLabelTool(n)
        Tool.exec_()
    else:
        print "Error in showLabelTool()"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday.
text() returns of type unicode and your method needs a string object, to convert just use `encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit out of context, but there's easier ways to change the label for a node in Nuke using `getInput` if that's what you're trying to accomplish:

```
new_label = nuke.getInput("enter label")
nuke.selectedNode()['label'].setValue(new_label)
```